# Validation Rule Error: Missing ')'

Tags: validation, validation-rule, error, dependent-picklist

- There are 2 dependent picklists: Scenario__c and Platform__c
- When selecting a picklist value for Scenario__c with anything other than "In-Progress" or "Confirmed"; the picklist Platform__c must have a value selected.

```
NOT(

   IF(ISPICKVAL(Scenario__c, "In-Progress" || "Confirmed"), 

       ISPICKVAL(Platform__c <> null), ""

      )
)
```

> Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, is that second parameter of `ISPICKVAL` function should be a `String`, not `Boolean`, which is in your case.

```
AND(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Scenario__c, "In-Progress"),
        ISPICKVAL(Scenario__c, "Confirmed")
    ),
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Platform__c))
)
```